# JQuery UI date picker does not disable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

Need help on this. I cannot disable my date picker in jquery. I did my research already but to no avail. Below is the code which does not enable/disable the datepicker.
[UPDATED]

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function pageLoad() {

        $(function () {
            $('#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../Images/CalendarIcon1.gif',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });

        });

        $(function () {
            $('#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../Images/CalendarIcon1.gif',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        });

        $("#<%=CheckBox_PayEvent.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if ($("#<%=CheckBox_PayEvent.ClientID %>").is(":checked")) {
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', true);
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("disable");

                $("#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', true);
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("disable");
            }
            else {
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', false);
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("enable");

                $("#<%= TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', false);
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("enable");
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does CheckBox_PayEvent have autopostback = true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason which i understand is when you check/uncheck checkbox it postbacks the page and set the datepicker again to textboxes.
Try this

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function pageLoad() {

        $(function () {
            $('#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../Images/CalendarIcon1.gif',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });

        });

        $(function () {
            $('#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../Images/CalendarIcon1.gif',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        });

        $("#<%=CheckBox_PayEvent.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if ($("#<%=CheckBox_PayEvent.ClientID %>").is(":checked")) {
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', true);
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("disable");

                $("#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', true);
                $("#<%=TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("disable");
            }
            else {
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', false);
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("enable");

                $("#<%= TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").attr('readonly', false);
                $("#<%= TextBox_EventEndDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("enable");
            }
            return false; //This line will stop the postback to occur
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: it still acts the same, but the check mark does not show in the checkbox. i also did a breakpoint, and it still recreates a new datepicker.

Answer (score 5):

2 ways that worked for me:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().datepicker('disable'); //disable [not disabled]
or .datepicker("disable");
```

No other methods works for me:

```
.datepicker("disabled"); 
.dpSetDisabled(false);
.datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

I use jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 2):

A little late with this answer but in case this is helpful for anyone else, I stumbled across this same issue and the common solution posted online ***.datepicker("disable")*** did not work for me either

I looked over the datePicker source and found the following, which did work for me. Maybe the correct answer is version dependent.

To disable control

```
$("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").dpSetDisabled(true);
```

To enable control

```
$("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").dpSetDisabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the function inside the disable logic. For example, I have a situation where I want the datepicker gone if the attached textbox is disabled that looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //Turn off datepicker if the textbox has been disabled.
    if(document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientID%>').disabled == true){
        $("#txtStartDate").datepicker('disable');
    }
    else { // Otherwise, enable and set up the .datepicker function 
        $("#txtStartDate").datepicker('enable');

        // .datepicker function goes here
        $('#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID%>').datepicker({
        showOn: "button", 
        buttonImage: "/Admin/Images/calendar.gif", 
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        }); 
    }      
});
```

I know the post is old, but hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#<%= TextBox_EventStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("disable");
```

Comment: I tried this one but it still does not work. I don't know what I have to do to be disabled.

Comment: i tried replicating it to my asp.net application. but it is not working. i'm using a checkbox instead of a button.

Answer (score 0):

using ({disabled: true}) definitely does not work, datepicker("disable") is what will do it.

Are you sure that the conditional statement is being met and the click event is being fired; are you sure the code is running?

Is it possible the space is being echoed by the server side code, so that ID being passed to JQuery is like this: "# ElementID"?

Comment: I tested my conditional statement and it is working. However, the datepicker image button gets disabled then it becomes enabled.

I'll update my code to let you see the changes.

Comment: Is this page live somewhere, or is it a test server?

Comment: Was just wondering if it was something I could look at directly? Is this the only javascript running on the page? You said it automatically becomes re-enabled so just wondering if there's something else affecting it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with asp, but is there a way to cancel the postback, like something similar to onsubmit = function(){return false}, or have it only return true when a submit button is clicked?

Comment: actually, i tried to disable the postback and it works. But i need it because i will enable/disable controls.